# PHP date(): minutes without leading zeros

Tags: php, date, format

I'd like to know if there is a formatting letter for PHP's `date()` that allows me to print minutes *without* leading zeros, or whether I have to manually test for and remove leading zeros?

Comment: May I ask WHY the hell there is no minutes without zeros ???

Comment: Yes please ask .. i want to hear that answer too ...

Comment: One reason: If you output the result of eg date("Y,n,j,G,i,s", xxx) to javascript, it'll throw a warning on octal numbers on 08 & 09 minutes & seconds.

Although this can be worked around by passing quoted: date("'Y','n','j','G','i','09'", xxx)

Comment: see my answer below... `abs( date( 'i' ) )` does not have the same issue as `intval()`

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Use:

```
$minutes = intval(date('i'));
```

Comment: Crazy PHP behaviour! It treats the int `09` as an octal number because of the leading zero - which will evaluate to `0` since `9` isn't a valid octal number. But it treats the string `09` as the decimal integer `9`. Good bye expected behaviour! :)

Comment: It's better to use `(int)date('i');` instead of `intval()`. It's supposed to be much faster.

Comment: Well, according to documentation, this is an expected behaviour due to second parameter of intval which is `base` and by default it is equal to 10.

PHP will treat input an octal number if base explicitly defined as `0` or `8`

Comment: @hek2mgl see my answer below... `abs( date( 'i' ) )` does not have the same issue as `intval()`

Comment: `echo +'05';`  results in printing the value `5`. So `+$date->format("your-format")` will return an integer :)

Answer (score 20):

For times with more information than just minutes:

`ltrim()` - Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string

```
ltrim(date('i:s'), '0');
```

returns:

```
8:24
```

Comment: this doesn't work on times less then 1 minute.. for example: 00:24 would result in :24

Comment: Perfectly fits into my function (..`elseif ($duration <= 3599 && $duration > 59) {`..)

Comment: It's a good solution but just a bad example, it should be just `ltrim(date('i'), 0)` and `ltrim(date('s'), 0)` separately :)

Answer (score 8):

According to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), the `date()` function does not have a placeholder for minutes without leading zeros.

You could, however, get that information by simply multiplying the dates, with a leading zero, by 1, turning it into an integer.

```
$minutesWithoutZero = 1* date( 'i' );
```

Comment: True. Just using bad old habits picked up in my javascript days.

Comment: +1 for the novel solution Lucanos. Thanks. I've gone with `Hippo`'s answer due to it's simplicity and non-hackiness ;-P

Answer (score 7):

I tried to find this for seconds as well, gave up the search and just casting the result as a int like this:

```
echo (int)date("s");
```

That will get rid of the leading zero's in a fast efficient way.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like it, but you could do something like...

```
echo date('g:') . ltrim(date('i'), '0');
```

Alternately, you could cast the second call to `date()` with `(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

This also works

```
$timestamp = time(); // Or Your timestamp. Skip passing $timestamp if you want current time
echo (int)date('i',$timestamp);
```

Comment: No need to add `time()` there.

Comment: @alex, I was actually trying to show where he could add his own timestamp

Comment: alex is right... `date( 'format_string' )` assumes `time()` as the second argument

Answer (score 2):

I use this format if I need a XXmXXs format:

```
//Trim leading 0's and the 'm' if no minutes
ltrim(ltrim(gmdate("i\ms\s", $seconds), '0'), 'm');
```

This will output the following:

```
12m34s
1m23s
12s
```

Comment: Awesome! Even better then @ScottA solution. This is my code (also with hours) `print ltrim(gmdate("H\hi\ms\s", $duration), '0mh');`

Answer (score 2):

i just did this one line solution

> $min = intval(date('i',strtotime($date)));

Using ltrim method may remove all the leading zeroes.For ex if '00' min.In this case this will remove all the zeroes and gives you empty result.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
function seconds2string($seconds) {
        if ($seconds == 0) {
            return '-';
        }
        if ($seconds < 60) {
            return date('0:s', $seconds);
        }
        if ($seconds < 3600) {
            return ltrim(date('i:s', $seconds), 0);
        }
        return date('G:i:s', $seconds);
}
```

This will output:

```
0 seconds:            -
10 seconds:        0:10
90 seconds:        1:30
301 seconds:       5:01
1804 seconds:     30:04
3601 seconds:   1:00:01
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
(int) date('i');
```

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski Thanks for response. Sorry, but my native language is not english, so for me hard to explain something in english. But I will try. `(int)` function works native in PHP. So it should works fast. But I didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Or in mySQL just multiply it by 1, like such:

```
select f1, ..., date_format( fldTime , '%i' ) * 1  as myTime, ..., ...
```

Comment: I didn't ask for a MySQL solution, but thank you for the alternative - I'll keep this in mind for MySQL-related formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_date = Date("n-j-Y");
echo $current_date;

// Result m-d-yy

9-10-2012
```

Answer (score 0):

A quickie from me. Tell me what you think:

```
<?php function _wo_leading_zero($n) {
    if(!isset($n[1])) return $n;

    if(strpos($n, '.') !== false) {
    $np = explode('.', $n); $nd = '.';
    }
    if(strpos($n, ',') !== false) {
    if(isset($np)) return false;
    $np = explode(',', $n); $nd = ',';
    }
    if(isset($np) && count($np) > 2) return false;
    $n = isset($np) ? $np[0] : $n;      

    $nn = ltrim($n, '0');
    if($nn == '') $nn = '0';
    return $nn.(isset($nd) ? $nd : '').(isset($np[1]) ? $np[1] : '');
}

echo '0 => '._wo_leading_zero('0').'<br/>'; // returns 0
echo '00 => '._wo_leading_zero('00').'<br/>'; // returns 0
echo '05 => '._wo_leading_zero('05').'<br/>'; // returns 5
echo '0009 => '._wo_leading_zero('0009').'<br/>'; //returns 9
echo '01 => '._wo_leading_zero('01').'<br/>'; //returns 1
echo '0000005567 => '._wo_leading_zero('0000005567').'<br/>'; //returns 5567
echo '000.5345453 => '._wo_leading_zero('000.5345453').'<br/>'; //returns 0.5345453
echo '000.5345453.2434 => '._wo_leading_zero('000.5345453.2434').'<br/>'; //returns false
echo '000.534,2434 => '._wo_leading_zero('000.534,2434').'<br/>'; //returns false

echo date('m').' => '._wo_leading_zero(date('m')).'<br/>';
echo date('s').' => '._wo_leading_zero(date('s')).'<br/>'; ?>
```

Comment: ~12 function calls to remove leading zeros. Your function could be broken down into this `(int) "001"`

Answer (score 0):

use PHP's absolute value function:

`abs( '09' ); // result = 9`

`abs( date( 'i' ) ); // result = minutes without leading zero`

Answer (score -2):

My Suggestion is Read this beautiful documentation it have all details of php date functions

**[Link of Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)**

And as per your question you can use `i - Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59)` Which return you minutes with leading zero(0).

And Also introducing `[Intval()][2]` function returns the integer value of a variable. You can not use the intval() function on an object

Comment: OP wants minutes WITHOUT leading zeros