# PHP date() Hours, Minutes and Seconds without leading zeros

Tags: php, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert seconds to Hour:Minute:Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172332/convert-seconds-to-hourminutesecond)

I've been searching all over the internet to find a good way of converting seconds into minutes:seconds without leading zeros. I already checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639047/php-date-minutes-without-leading-zeros), which is the only one I was even able to find, however none of those answers look very good. Perhaps they are the only and best way to achieve this, however I would hope not.

I have done this and it gives me the number of minutes without the leading zeros, however I am unable to get the seconds. The only way I can think of doing it this way would be to do a few lines of math and such, but that seems like an awful lot of work for something as simple as this... which I don't know why PHP doesn't have it built in for minutes and seconds anyways....

```
intval(gmdate("i:s", $duration));
```

**Edit**
All I am trying to do is to convert the number of seconds in a video, into a H:M:S format.

Comment: What do you need `intval()` for? **Why** did you add it?

Comment: Well, it is one of the answers on the other overflow question in my question, it removes the zeros, and everything else as well..

Comment: no it doesn't. Please read documentation before you apply functions randomly: http://php.net/intval

Comment: Like I said, I didn't apply it myself, it was one of the few answers on the only topic of this, and it was suggested this way a couple of times if I'm not mistaken. 
Also, I was just stating what it did do to my date, which it did remove the zeros and non numerical values.

Comment: "Like I said, I didn't apply it myself, it was one of the few answers on the only topic" --- even worse. It's a community of programmers, not code-copy-pasters.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that post, I want to remove leading zeros.. that one doesn't.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implode(
    ':',
    array_map(
        function($i) { return intval($i, 10); },
        explode(':', gmdate('H:i:s', $duration))
    )
)
```

> however what about if hour==0 then do not print 0: and just have m:s

```
preg_replace(
    '~^0:~',
    '', 
    implode(
        ':',
        array_map(
            function($i) { return intval($i, 10); },
            explode(':', gmdate('H:i:s', $duration))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: good job on having everything in 1 line :).

Comment: Thanks, this does have the expected outcome.

I did not ask this, however what about if hour==0 then do not print 0: and just have m:s

Comment: @Dylan Cross: see the version 2

Comment: For all durations < 86400 seconds :)

Comment: Actually... I feel horribly stupid now, just doing this is all I really needed. I realized afterwards that I actually didn't want the leading zeros in the seconds removed at all. `preg_replace('~^00:0~','', gmdate("H:i:s", $duration));`

Answer (score 2):

I would just write it iteratively:

```
function duration_to_timestring($duration)
{
        $s = [];
        if ($duration > 3600) {
                $s[] = floor($duration / 3600);
                $duration %= 3600;
        }
        $s[] = floor($duration / 60);
        $s[] = floor($duration % 60);

        return join(':', $s);
}
```

Comment: This would be good too, although I still can't figure out why php doesn't include minutes and seconds without leading zeros.

Comment: @DylanCross Only the privileged know why, perhaps they ran out of useful letters to use as format specifiers ;-)

Answer (score 1):

gmdate takes a timestamp as the second parameter.
You should do something like this:

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998) + $duration);
```

intval should not be there, as you are getting a string and are transforming it to an int again. With H:i:s you have 10:40:05.
This will however not work if you have the duration > then 24h.

Comment: I want to remove the leading zeros though, the code above doesn't.

Comment: If you want without the leading 0 then you will have to use 
$hours = date("h", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998) + $duration);
$minutes = intval(date("i", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998) + $duration));
$seconds = intval(date("s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998) + $duration));

Comment: I edited my code, I have a feeling that you should use date instead of gmdate. Otherwise now might not be accurate depending on the server date.

Comment: Thanks, the only problem is that the Hour one, when it should be zero, is now 12, but before you edited it, it was 5.

Comment: you are right it should be  $hours = date("G", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998) + $duration);